# How to remove secondary Linux OS from disk and boot?

Tags: linux, windows-10, multi-boot, uninstall

I have Windows 10 as primary OS installed and 2 Linux versions. The boot menu is set by GRUB and Windows 10 is the first option for boot.

May someone suggest me how would be a safe way to delete/uninstall one of the Linux versions and after that have the boot menu showing the only 2 remaining OS?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exact process will depend on which Linux install wrote the bootloader, and what that install sees as `/`.

Win10, LinuxA, LinuxB, assume you are keeping LinuxA and it is LinuxA's GRUB that is "in charge" at the moment.

Boot LinuxA, ensure that nothing from LinuxB is mounted, and use `fdisk`, `gparted`, etc. to simply delete the partition(s) for LinuxB.  Once they are deleted, make the bootloader (GRUB) aware of the changes by running `update-grub`

Where it gets tricky is  if you want to keep LinuxB but LinuxA has the boot loader or vice versa.

In that case, you need to boot the Linux you are keeping, get GRUB set up and configured, and install GRUB to the MBR.  Then reboot, go back into that Linux install, and remove the other Linux install.  Run the `update-grub` and you should be good to go.

Comment: Hi ivanivan. Thanks for your answer. As you assumed about the tricky part, happens that I don't know which of both Linux has de bootloader. Do you know a guide to follow for this part you say `get GRUB set up and configured, and install GRUB to the MBR` or if you have chance explain me inn more detail please. Thanks again

Comment: Thanks ivanivan, I was able to make without issues following your suggestions :)